# set default homepage in mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile

I was looking all around and couldn't find any recent answer to this:
is it possible to set the homepage for a mobile browser (on iphone/android: safari/chrome/browser/etc) using a code (JS, PHP, whatever) ?

thanks

Comment: Not likely. I do not even have a homepage on my iphone

Comment: chrome doesn't have one as well.
seems like the only option will be to use bookmarks (and open the bookmark i.s.o the browser.

thanks